# How to make macros that would implement different of args to structure baaed on given tuple?

Tags: rust, macros, arguments, implementation

I tried to make structure that contains tuple that has different size. Structure implements function `get` that would return tuple created as shown in example.

```
// Passed tuple with four elements into macros
impl <A0, A1, A2, A3> Cont<(A0, A1, A2, A3)> {
    fn get(&self) -> (A0, A1, A2, A3) {
        (self.data.0, self.data.1, self.data.2, self.data.3)
    }
}
// Passed tuple with five elements into macros
impl <A0, A1, A2, A3, A4> Cont<(A0, A1, A2, A3, A4)> {
    fn get(&self) -> (A0, A1, A2, A3, A4) {
        (self.data.0, self.data.1, self.data.2, self.data.3, self.data.4)
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to use cycle as `A|number|`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can or should do, is not care about the tuples. One generic parameter can cover all tuples, see this:

```rust
struct Foo<T> {
    data: T,
}

impl<T> Foo<T> {
    fn get(&self) -> &T {
        &self.data
    }
}

fn example() {
    let foo = Foo { data: (1, "hello") };
    assert_eq!(foo.get(), &(1, "hello"));

    let foo = Foo {
        data: (1, "hello", 2),
    };
    assert_eq!(foo.get(), &(1, "hello", 2));
}
```

## Edit

If you want limit what type can hold, you usually do it with traits to keep common functions names.

```
macro_rules! impl_tuple {
    ($(
        ($($p:ident),*);
    )*) => {
        $(
            impl<$($p),*> sealed::Sealed for ($($p,)*) {}
        )*
    };
}

mod sealed {
    pub trait Sealed {}
}

pub trait ValidData: sealed::Sealed {}
impl<T: sealed::Sealed> ValidData for T {}

impl_tuple! {
    (A);
    (A, B, C);
    (A, B, C, D, E);
}

struct Foo<T: ValidData> {
    data: T,
}

impl<T: ValidData> Foo<T> {
    fn get(&self) -> &T {
        &self.data
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo { data: 1 }; // fails
                               // the trait bound `{integer}: Sealed` is not satisfied
                               // the following other types implement trait `Sealed`:
                               //   (A, B, C)
                               //   (A, B, C, D, E)
                               //   (A,) [E0277]
    let foo = Foo { data: (1,) }; // ok
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't what I need. I cannot have struct that hasn't any specification about the data it stores. And cannot have struct that stores var with `std::marker::Tuple + Sized` . The hole point is to make the macros that would implement the given length of tuple.